# How to run a count based on a subset of a select query

Tags: sql, count, countif

I have a database that lists Part Number by the associated model group. Roughly half of the parts are unique to a model group. I was wondering if there is a way to select only the part numbers that are unique to a model group.

I found a non-elegant workaround to the problem with the following code:

'''

```
Select Distinct

                            a.*
                            ,b.count
                from
                        (SELECT
                                [PART_NO]
                                ,[Family]
                          FROM [dbo].[Mapping_Perkins_Parts_Series_Models] ) a
                    left join 
                        (SELECT distinct
                                [PART_NO]
                                ,count(part_no) as count
                          FROM [dbo].[Mapping_Perkins_Parts_Series_Models]
                          group by part_no ) b

                on b.PART_NO = a.PART_NO
                where count = 1
```

'''

I am wondering if it is possible to do this in a single select statement, rather than a nested select statement? The issue I keep running into is that I have to include all fields in my group by and once I do that any instances of a part occuring twice but with different families are treated as unique records.

'''

Data Set: (Part_No,Family)

```
  (1, a)
  (1, b)
  (2, a)
  (3, b)
  (4, a)
  (4, b)
  (5, b)
  (6, a)
```

Expected Result : (Part_No, Family) (2, a) (3,b) (5,b) (6,a)

Comment: I only see one query in your question, so it is quite unclear what you mean by "single query".

Comment: Sample data, please. And the expected result.

Comment: Added in example data set and expected result. Couldn't figure out table formatting so put pairs in parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your RDBMS supports window functions, you could do a window count in a subquery and filter in the outer query, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Part_No) cnt
    FROM mytable t
) x
WHERE cnt = 1
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.. I get the same resulting set that I did from the query I posted above. Will have to research what can be done with partition by seems very useful... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
select * from
(
  select PART_NO,count(distinct Family) PartFamCount
  from [dbo].[Mapping_Perkins_Parts_Series_Models]
  group by PART_NO
)x
where PartFamCount=1
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this! So I can't tell whats going on here, but I get triple the part numbers than I should. I think the count here is only counting the occurrence of family when I need it to count the occurrence of part number.